# How to upgrade SharePoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: upgrade

A SharePoint solution consists of 2 parts:

- What is installed in production
- The solution in Visual Studio

The infrastructure consultants recommend running in the in place upgrade. But then what happens to the solution, and what happens next time you try and deploy the solution.

The dev consultants recommended upgrading the sollution, installing to new production environment and transfering contents.

Question is how to upgrade? Is one of these approaches better, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say there is no single best answer to your question. If you look for general answer then yes in-place approach might be better.

However it really depends on your situation. In case you are running your SharePoint on Windows 2003 32bit upgrading in-place on that platform is not recommended (you would have to upgrade Windows and everything else first). Even if you are running on Windows 2008 64bit now, you still need to check the HW reqs to see if you have good hardware for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect that the product is ready for these type of changes. Meaning that the product is ready to expect that the manifest.xml of a solution can change because of newly added options with 2010. Also the changes of the feature.xml is, hopefully, supported.

So.. I'd recommend to go with the infrastructure recommendation when doing the upgrade of your environment.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of my Ignite training it wasn't working like a charm yet. As you know, in VS 2010 there are now SharePoint templates. The conversion process does convert your VS 2008 project to a SharePoint 2010 project, but it's still a bit messy and you'll have to do come cleaning.

What does work though is just converting your project the oldschool way (like you convert normal dev projects) so that it can be opened with Visual Studio 2010. Then you will be able to convert your solution on your SharePoint 2010 environment.

Take into account that the UI will not be changed. So if you develop webparts they may look outdated.